# How to access user's Calendar on Android device?

Tags: android, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm writing simple Android app to filter some events from user's calendar. The questions is, **what is the best way to access it?**

One option that comes to my mind is through Google Calendar Data API where I will have to authenticate the user and synchronize with the calendar in my app.

Is there any way to access the calendar through Android? Meaning that I will only access it locally and Android itself will handle the authentication, synchronization, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way to access the calendar through Android? Meaning that I will only access it locally and Android itself will handle the authentication, synchronization, etc.

There is no documented and supported way of doing this. Please use the Google Calendar GData API.

Comment: from Android 4.0 it is being supported

Comment: @MayuMayooresan: Correct. However, that still only affects Android 4.0+ devices -- there is no back-port of that API. Also, I get the impression that you can do more with the GData API than you can with `CalendarContract`, though I am far from certain on this.

Answer (score 4):

I am not an android Geek but here are few suggestions as far as I know,

Before Android 2.0 there was no support for this...But I think this works with 2.1 and 2.2, more over some developers already implemented this in their apps.

check the links below.

http://jimblackler.net/blog/?p=151

http://www.developer.com/article.php/3850276

PS:Sorry for second link format, I am new here, so cannot post more than 1 link.

Comment: Actually, this stuff has been around since way before 2.1, but it's unsupported, undocumented, and you'll find that it doesn't work on certain phone models depending on the customization done to the OS, for example HTC SenseUI on some phones breaks this code.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good example of accessing Google Calendar Data API from Android using the [Google API Client Library for Java](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) at [calendar-v2-atom-android-sample](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-v2-atom-android-sample/instructions.html?r=default).  With this solution, Android takes care of the authentication/authorization, but not the synchronization.

Disclaimer: I am an owner of the Google API Client Library for Java project.