# Export android calendar to VCS

Tags: java, android, calendar, vcalendar

How to export the events in a calendar in android phone to vcs file using code. Or is there any other format that I can export all events in calendar?

How can I do this in android?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [no documented internal calendar API on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286237/how-to-access-users-calendar-on-android-device). You'll need to use [Google Calendar API](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/).

There is an unofficial, unsupported, not-recommended and non-future-proof way of accessing Calendar app internal database: http://www.developer.com/article.php/3850276

VCS files are in [vCalendar format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCalendar#vCalendar_1.0), which is old format. The replacement is [iCalendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar). This is a simple, one property-per-line format, which is simple to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Google APIs Client Library for Java to access the user's Google Calendar data. [Here is a specific sample](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse?repo=samples#hg/calendar-v2-atom-android-sample) from that project for accessing Google Calendar from Android using this library. [Here is a conference video](http://youtu.be/9fBcrzA-hWY) describing the use of this library.