# Android calendar event

Tags: android, calendar, scheduled-tasks, reminders

I want to write an application that is triggered when a calendar reminder occurs. I also looked at android developer site and didnt find anything about it

I want to create something like this (however it doesnt work for me). how can i do it?

```
public class SchedulerSetupReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String APP_TAG = "com.hascode.android";

    private static final int EXEC_INTERVAL = 20 * 1000;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context ctx, final Intent intent) {
        Log.d(APP_TAG, "SchedulerSetupReceiver.onReceive() called");
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    }

}
```

Comment: access to Google Calendar in not part of API. `Calendar` you are trying to instantiate is something **different** you think it is.

Comment: thanks for answer..so there is no way to do some listener to the notification and check if there is a calendar event notification?

Comment: No, no broadcast on that. Dig in the links in answers there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286237/how-to-access-users-calendar-on-android-device though